# The columns of AB are linearly dependent. Are the columns of B linearly dependent? show why or why not this would be true.

Tags: linear-algebra

The columns of AB are linearly dependent. Are the columns of B linearly dependent? show why or why not this would be true or provide an example.

Comment: Let $B$ be the identity matrix, and let $A$ be the $0$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are matrices, no because if $A$ is the zero matrix, and $B$ is any invertible matrix, $AB=0$ and therefore has linearly dependent columns but $B$ has linearly independent columns by Invertible Matrix Theorem.